# Conversion between trig functions and hyperbolic trig functions

Tags: functions, trigonometry, circles, graphing-functions, parametric

Using trig identities we can see that  $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x =  \tanh^2 x + \text{sech}^2 x = 1$ , and so the parametric graph $(\cos t, \sin t)$ is similar to $(\text{sech} t, \tanh t)$. The first graph produces a semicircle when $-\frac \pi2 \le t \le \frac \pi2$ and the second graph when $-\infty \lt t \lt \infty$. My question is if it is possible to convert between the graphs;  e.g. if there is a function $f$ where $(\text{sech} t, \tanh t) = (\cos f(t), \sin f(t))$.

Comment: See the [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function): it is defined by
$$ \operatorname{gd}{x} = \int_0^x \operatorname{sech}{y} \, dy $$
In particular, this can be expressed, by changing variables, as
$$ \operatorname{gd}{x} = (\operatorname{sgn}{x}) \arccos{(\operatorname{sech}{x})} = \arcsin{(\tanh{x})}, $$
so
$$ \cos{(\operatorname{gd}{x})} = \operatorname{sech}{x},\\
\sin{(\operatorname{gd}{x})} = \tanh{x}, $$
and then everything follows as you wish, since $\operatorname{gd}:(-\infty,\infty) \to (-1,1)$ bijectively.

Comment: Thanks. So, could gd be thought of some sort of a conversion between a radian value and a hyperbolic angle?

Comment: Yes, essentially. The most remarkable thing is probably the amount of ways you can write gd as inverse trig of hyperbolics: there's just something about that particular integral. No doubt someone's written an article about it. It lets you relate them without complex numbers, too.